# Finding the Limiting Distribution of an order statistic

Tags: mathematical-statistics, order-statistics

I've been told that the sequence X1, X2,...,Xn are iid from Exp(y) with density function f(x)=(1/y)*exp(-x/y). I've been asked to find the limiting distribution of Wn = Xn:n - ylog(n) where Xn:n is the first order statistic.

However, I feel totally stuck. I feel as if I need more information on the sequence of random variables in order to solve the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/ExponentialM.pdf

Comment: "...$X_{n:n}$ is the first order statistic"? ...  I'd be inclined call $X_{1:n}$ the 'first' order statistic.

Comment: @MONODA43: that's for the minimum, which you'd normally call the first order statistic, but in this case the notation and the centering of the limit distribution suggest the poster means the maximum